# Flutter add time to chat message

Tags: firebase, flutter, datetime, chat, message

I have to create a chat in my app. The problem is that the time when someone sent his message is not placed properly in the chatscreen and the number is not correct or long. The time should look like this (13:36). Does anyone know how I can put the time under the message like whatsapp does? This is my ChatScreen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj9s9.png)

```
class MessageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final bool sendByMe;
  final int time;

  MessageTile({@required this.message, @required this.sendByMe, @required this.time});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: sendByMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text( sendByMe ? time.toString() : time.toString(),style: sendByMe ?
        TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Orbitron', fontSize: 7.0,):
        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Orbitron', fontSize: 7.0,) ,
       ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 3,
              bottom: 3,
              left: sendByMe ? 0 : 24,
              right: sendByMe ? 24 : 0),
          alignment: sendByMe ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Container(
            margin: sendByMe
                ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 30)
                : EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 17, bottom: 17, left: 20, right: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: sendByMe ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(9),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(9),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(9),
                ) :
                BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(9),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(9),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(9)),
               color: sendByMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.white
            ),
            child: Text(message,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                    fontSize: 9.0,),),
            ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using int datatype to store your time data, instead of DateTime?

Comment: No, actually just so that the messages are sorted by time so from top to bottom

Comment: Well then, it would be more appropriate to store the time as DateTime or String. You can sort them using their compareTo() method.

Comment: Like how? Could you show example

Answer (score 0):

Replace `time.toString()` to `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time).toString()`

```
child: Text( sendByMe ? DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time).toString() : DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time).toString(),style: sendByMe ?
      TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Orbitron', fontSize: 9.0,):
      TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Orbitron', fontSize: 9.0,),
      ),
```